# React JS onClick set state of clicked index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I update `isSelected` to true for the item that the user clicks on?

Here is my `handleSelect` function so far:

```
handleSelect(i) {
  //Get Genres
  let genres = this.state.allGenres;
  genres = genres.map((val, index) => {
    //val.isSelected = index === true;
    return val;
  }); 
  //Set State
  this.setState({
    allGenres: genres
  })
}
```

This function is passed down correctly via props and is working, the issue I'm having is with the logic.

The current logic sets all items in the array to true which is incorrect. I only want to update / toggle the state of the item the user clicked.

I have an array of objects within state, here is what one of the objects  looks like:

```
state = {
    allGenres: [
      {
        id: 1,
        genreTitle: 'Horror',
        isSelected: false,
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: the `i` passed to `handleSelect` refers to what ? The index in the `genres` array or the `id` of the genre, or something else ?

Answer (score 2):

**Here's how we can do it:**

1. On each clicked Genre, we get its `id`.
2. After we have the `id`, then we toggle the selected genre `isSelected` flag.
3. Please follow `updateGenres` method, to check how we did it in an immutable way.

```
updateGenres(selectedId) {
   const { allGenres } = this.state

   this.setState({
     // Here we make sure we don't mutate the state
     allGenres: allGenres.map(genre => ({
        ...genre,
        // Toggle the clicked one, and reset all others to be `false`.
        isSelected: genre.id === selectedId
        // If you want to keep the values of the rest genres, then the check should be: 
        // isSelected: (genre.id === selectedId) ? !genre.isSelected : genre.isSelected
     }))
   })
}

renderGenres() {
  const { allGenres } = this.state

  return allGenres.map(genre => <Gengre onClick={() => this.updateGenres(genre.id) })
}

render() {
  return <div>{this.renderGenres()}</div>
}
```

**The benefit of this approach** is that you don't depend on the `index` of the `allGenres` and your toggle implementation will be decoupled to the presentation. Imagine if you change the genres sort (from ASC to DESC), then you have to change your toggle logic too.

Comment: This isn't what I'm asking for sorry.

Comment: `isSelected: (genre.id === selectedId)` this will also work

Comment: @Harish, but he wants to toggle only the clicked one (without affecting the rest genres), because of this I do this `(genre.id === selectedId) ? !genre.isSelected : genre.isSelected`

Comment: as we are iterating over `allGenres` on each click and updating the value for `isSelected`. In both ways, value of `isSelected`  may be same but each time it will be updated.

Comment: With `genre.id === selectedId` will make only the clicked Genre `isSelected === true`, and all others genres will be `false`. With `(genre.id === selectedId) ? !genre.isSelected : genre.isSelected` will NOT change the others genres flag (because some of them can be already clicked, therefore to be `true`). It will toggle only the clicked one.

Comment: ohh, I thought there will be only one item selected which was clicked at last

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172293/discussion-between-harish-and-jordan-enev).

Comment: @Filth can you please check the updated answer?  Also if you have any questions, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is that maintain `allGenres` and `selectedGenre` separately in `state`  
So `handleSelect` will be like

```
handleSelect(id) {
  this.setState({
    selectedGenre: id
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `i` passed to `handleSelect` is the index of the genre in the `genres` array then

```
handleSelect(i) {
  //Get Genres
  let genres = this.state.allGenres;
  genres = genres.map((val, index) => {
    val.isSelected = index === i;
    return val;
  }); 

  //Set State
  this.setState({
    allGenres: genres
  })
}
```

if the `i` refers to the `id` of the genre then

```
handleSelect(i) {
  //Get Genres
  let genres = this.state.allGenres;
  genres = genres.map((val) => {
    val.isSelected = val.id === i;
    return val;
  }); 
  //Set State
  this.setState({
    allGenres: genres
  })
}
```

Comment: It's better not coupling the presentation (rendering and indexes) with the toggle functionality, relying on the `index`. It's error-prone. For example - Changing the sort of genres from ASC to DESC.

Comment: @JordanEnev if you were to re-order the array then the list would be re-rendered and so the `i` would be re-bound correctly. I would agree though that using `index` is not the best idea, but it depends on what the OP is trying to achieve and what the rest of his code is doing (*which is not posted*)

Comment: Here I mainly referred to `if the i refers to the id of the genre then`. However, generally relying to the `index` is risky.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you have some components being rendered, and that you want to click in these components... You could use `bind` and pass to the callback function the index of the array... for example:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      allGenres: [{
        id: 1,
        genreTitle: 'Horror',
        isSelected: false
      }]
    }
  }

  handleSelect(i) {
    //Get Genres
    let genres = this.state.allGenres;
      genres = genres.map((val, index) => {
      val.isSelected = index === i;
      return val;
    });
    //Set State
    this.setState({
      allGenres: genres
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {allGenres} = this.state;

    return (
      <ul>
        :D
        {allGenres.map((genre, i) => (
          <li onClick={this.handleSelect.bind(this, i)}>
            {genre.genreTitle} {genre.isSelected && 'Is Selected'}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using `bind` in the onClick callback from the `li`, this way I have access to the genre index in your callback.

There are some other ways of doing this though, since you have the id of the genre, you might want to use that instead of the index, but it's up to you to decided.